# Modifying perl script to not print duplicates and extract sequences of a certain length

Tags: perl

I want to first apologize for the biological nature of this post. I thought I should post some background first. I have a set of gene files that contain anywhere from one to five DNA sequences from different species. I used a bash shell script to perform blastn with each gene file as a query and a file of all transcriptome sequences (`all_transcriptome_seq.fasta`) from the five species as the subject. I now want to process these output files (and there are many) so that I can get all subject sequences that hit into one file per gene, with duplicate sequences removed (except to keep one), and ensure I'm getting the length of the sequences that actually hit the query.

Here is what the blastn output looks like for one gene file (columns: `qseqid qlen sseqid slen qframe qstart qend sframe sstart send evalue bitscore pident nident length`)

```
Acur_01000750.1_OFAS014956-RA-EXON04    248 Apil_comp17195_c0_seq1  1184    1   1   248 1   824 1072    2e-73    259    85.60   214 250
Acur_01000750.1_OFAS014956-RA-EXON04    248 Atri_comp5613_c0_seq1   1067    1   2   248 1   344 96  8e-97    337    91.16   227 249
Acur_01000750.1_OFAS014956-RA-EXON04    248 Acur_01000750.1 992 1   1   248 1   655 902 1e-133   459    100.00  248 248
Acur_01000750.1_OFAS014956-RA-EXON04    248 Btri_comp17734_c0_seq1  1001    1   1   248 1   656 905 5e-69    244    84.40   211 250
Btri_comp17734_c0_seq1_OFAS014956-RA-EXON04 250 Atri_comp5613_c0_seq1   1067    1   2   250 1   344 96  1e-60    217    82.33   205 249
Btri_comp17734_c0_seq1_OFAS014956-RA-EXON04 250 Acur_01000750.1 992 1   1   250 1   655 902 5e-69    244    84.40   211 250
Btri_comp17734_c0_seq1_OFAS014956-RA-EXON04 250 Btri_comp17734_c0_seq1  1001    1   1   250 1   656 905 1e-134   462    100.00  250 250
```

I've been working on a perl script that would, in short, take the `sseqid` column to pull out the corresponding sequences from the `all_transcriptome_seq.fasta` file, place these into a new file, and trim the transcripts to the `sstart` and `send` positions. Here is the script, so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

############################################################################
# blastn_post-processing.pl v. 1.0 by Michael F., XXXXXX
############################################################################

my($progname) = $0;

############################################################################
# Initialize variables
############################################################################

my($jter);

my($com);
my($t1);

if ( @ARGV != 2 ) {
    print "Usage:\n  \$ $progname <infile> <transcriptomes>\n";
    print "  infile         = tab-delimited blastn text file\n";
    print "  transcriptomes = fasta file of all transcriptomes\n";
    print "exiting...\n";
    exit;
}

my($infile)=$ARGV[0];
my($transcriptomes)=$ARGV[1];

############################################################################
# Read the input file
############################################################################
print "Reading the input file... ";
open (my $INF, $infile) or die "Unable to open file";
my @data = <$INF>;
print @data;
close($INF) or die "Could not close file $infile.\n";
my($nlines) = $#data + 1;
my($inlines) = $nlines - 1;
print "$nlines blastn hits read\n\n";

############################################################################
# Extract hits and place sequences into new file
############################################################################
my @temparray;
my @templine;
my($seqfname);

open ($INF, $infile) or die "Could not open file $infile for input.\n";
@temparray = <$INF>;
close($INF) or die "Could not close file $infile.\n";
$t1 = $#temparray + 1;
print "$infile\t$t1\n";
$seqfname = "$infile" . ".fasta";
if ( -e $seqfname ) {
        print "    --> $seqfname exists. overwriting\n";
        unlink($seqfname);
    }   

# iterate through the individual hits
for ($jter=0; $jter<$t1; $jter++) {
    (@templine) = split(/\s+/, $temparray[$jter]);
    $com = "./extract_from_genome2 $transcriptomes $templine[2] $templine[8] $templine[9] $templine[2]";
    # print "$com\n";
    system("$com");
    system("cat temp.3 >> $seqfname");
    } # end for ($jter=0; $jter<$t1...

# Arguments for "extract_from_genome2"
#   // argv[1] = name of genome file
#   // argv[2] = gi number for contig
#   // argv[3] = start of subsequence
#   // argv[4] = end of subsequence
#   // argv[5] = name of output sequence
```

Using this script, here is the output I'm getting:

```
>Apil_comp17195_c0_seq1
GATTCTTGCATCTGCAGTAAGACCAGAAATGCTCATTCCTATATGGCTATCTAATGGTATTATTTTTTTCTGATGTGCTGATAATTCAGACGAAGCTCTTTTAAGAGCCACAAGAACTGCATACTGCTTGTTTTTTACTCCAACAGTAGCAGCTCCCAGTTTTACAGCTTCCATTGCATATTCGACTTGGTGCAGGCGTCCCTGGGGACTCCAGACGGTAACGTCAGAATCATACTGGTTACGGAACA
>Atri_comp5613_c0_seq1
GAGAATTCTAGCATCAGCAGTGAGGCCTGAAATACTCATGCCTATGTGACTATCTAGAGGTATTATTTTTTTTTGATGAGCTGACAGTTCAGAAGAAGCTCTTTTGAGAGCTACAAGAACTGCATACTGTTTATTTTTTACTCCAACTGTTGCTGCTCCAAGCTTTACAGCCTCCATTGCATATTCCACTTGGTGTAAACGCCCCTGAGGACTCCATACCGTAACATCAGAATCATACTGATTACGGA
>Acur_01000750.1
GAATTCTAGCGTCAGCAGTGAGTCCTGAAATACTCATCCCTATGTGGCTATCTAGAGGTATTATTTTTTCTGATGGGCCGACAGTTCAGAGGATGCTCTTTTAAGAGCCACAAGAACTGCATACTCTTTATTTTTACTCCAACAGTAGCAGCTCCAAGCTTCACAGCCTCCATTGCATATTCCACCTGGTGTAAACGTCCCTGAGGGCTCCATACCGTAACATCAGAATCATACTGGTTACGGAACA
>Btri_comp17734_c0_seq1
GAATCCTTGCATCTGCAGTAAGTCCAGAAATGCTCATTCCAATATGGCTATCTAATGGTATTATTTTTTTCTGGTGAGCAGACAATTCAGATGATGCTCTTTTAAGAGCTACCAGTACTGCAAAATCATTGTTCTTCACTCCAACAGTTGCAGCACCTAATTTGACTGCCTCCATTGCATACTCCACTTGGTGCAATCTTCCCTGAGGGCTCCATACCGTAACATCAGAATCATACTGGTTACGGAACA
>Atri_comp5613_c0_seq1
GAGAATTCTAGCATCAGCAGTGAGGCCTGAAATACTCATGCCTATGTGACTATCTAGAGGTATTATTTTTTTTTGATGAGCTGACAGTTCAGAAGAAGCTCTTTTGAGAGCTACAAGAACTGCATACTGTTTATTTTTTACTCCAACTGTTGCTGCTCCAAGCTTTACAGCCTCCATTGCATATTCCACTTGGTGTAAACGCCCCTGAGGACTCCATACCGTAACATCAGAATCATACTGATTACGGA
>Acur_01000750.1
GAATTCTAGCGTCAGCAGTGAGTCCTGAAATACTCATCCCTATGTGGCTATCTAGAGGTATTATTTTTTCTGATGGGCCGACAGTTCAGAGGATGCTCTTTTAAGAGCCACAAGAACTGCATACTCTTTATTTTTACTCCAACAGTAGCAGCTCCAAGCTTCACAGCCTCCATTGCATATTCCACCTGGTGTAAACGTCCCTGAGGGCTCCATACCGTAACATCAGAATCATACTGGTTACGGAACA
>Btri_comp17734_c0_seq1
GAATCCTTGCATCTGCAGTAAGTCCAGAAATGCTCATTCCAATATGGCTATCTAATGGTATTATTTTTTTCTGGTGAGCAGACAATTCAGATGATGCTCTTTTAAGAGCTACCAGTACTGCAAAATCATTGTTCTTCACTCCAACAGTTGCAGCACCTAATTTGACTGCCTCCATTGCATACTCCACTTGGTGCAATCTTCCCTGAGGGCTCCATACCGTAACATCAGAATCATACTGGTTACGGAACA
```

As you can see, it's pretty close to what I'm wanting. Here are the two issues I have and cannot seem to figure out how to resolve with my script. The **first** is that a sequence may occur more than once in the `sseqid` column, and with the script in its current form, it will print out duplicates of these sequences. I only need one. How can I modify my script to not duplicate sequences (i.e., how do I only retain one but remove the other duplicates)? Expected output:

```
>Apil_comp17195_c0_seq1
GATTCTTGCATCTGCAGTAAGACCAGAAATGCTCATTCCTATATGGCTATCTAATGGTATTATTTTTTTCTGATGTGCTGATAATTCAGACGAAGCTCTTTTAAGAGCCACAAGAACTGCATACTGCTTGTTTTTTACTCCAACAGTAGCAGCTCCCAGTTTTACAGCTTCCATTGCATATTCGACTTGGTGCAGGCGTCCCTGGGGACTCCAGACGGTAACGTCAGAATCATACTGGTTACGGAACA
>Atri_comp5613_c0_seq1
GAGAATTCTAGCATCAGCAGTGAGGCCTGAAATACTCATGCCTATGTGACTATCTAGAGGTATTATTTTTTTTTGATGAGCTGACAGTTCAGAAGAAGCTCTTTTGAGAGCTACAAGAACTGCATACTGTTTATTTTTTACTCCAACTGTTGCTGCTCCAAGCTTTACAGCCTCCATTGCATATTCCACTTGGTGTAAACGCCCCTGAGGACTCCATACCGTAACATCAGAATCATACTGATTACGGA
>Acur_01000750.1
GAATTCTAGCGTCAGCAGTGAGTCCTGAAATACTCATCCCTATGTGGCTATCTAGAGGTATTATTTTTTCTGATGGGCCGACAGTTCAGAGGATGCTCTTTTAAGAGCCACAAGAACTGCATACTCTTTATTTTTACTCCAACAGTAGCAGCTCCAAGCTTCACAGCCTCCATTGCATATTCCACCTGGTGTAAACGTCCCTGAGGGCTCCATACCGTAACATCAGAATCATACTGGTTACGGAACA
>Btri_comp17734_c0_seq1
GAATCCTTGCATCTGCAGTAAGTCCAGAAATGCTCATTCCAATATGGCTATCTAATGGTATTATTTTTTTCTGGTGAGCAGACAATTCAGATGATGCTCTTTTAAGAGCTACCAGTACTGCAAAATCATTGTTCTTCACTCCAACAGTTGCAGCACCTAATTTGACTGCCTCCATTGCATACTCCACTTGGTGCAATCTTCCCTGAGGGCTCCATACCGTAACATCAGAATCATACTGGTTACGGAACA
```

The **second** is the script is not quite extracting the right base pairs. It's super close, off by one or two, but its not exact.

For example, take the first subject hit `Apil_comp17195_c0_seq1`. The `sstart` and `send` values are 824 and 1072, respectively. When I go to the `all_transcriptome_seq.fasta`, I get

```
AAGATTCTTGCATCTGCAGTAAGACCAGAAATGCTCATTCCTATATGGCTATCTAATGGTATTATTTTTTTCTGATGTGCTGATAATTCAGACGAAGCTCTTTTAAGAGCCACAAGAACTGCATACTGCTTGTTTTTTACTCCAACAGTAGCAGCTCCCAGTTTTACAGCTTCCATTGCATATTCGACTTGGTGCAGGCGTCCCTGGGGACTCCAGACGGTAACGTCAGAATCATACTGGTTACGGAAC
```

at that base pair range, not

```
GATTCTTGCATCTGCAGTAAGACCAGAAATGCTCATTCCTATATGGCTATCTAATGGTATTATTTTTTTCTGATGTGCTGATAATTCAGACGAAGCTCTTTTAAGAGCCACAAGAACTGCATACTGCTTGTTTTTTACTCCAACAGTAGCAGCTCCCAGTTTTACAGCTTCCATTGCATATTCGACTTGGTGCAGGCGTCCCTGGGGACTCCAGACGGTAACGTCAGAATCATACTGGTTACGGAACA
```

as outputted by my script, which is what I'm expecting. You will also notice that the sequence outputted by my script is slightly shorter than it should be. Does anyone know how I can fix these issues in my script?

Thanks, and sorry for the lengthy post!

**Edit 1: a solution was offered that work for some of the infiles. However, some were causing the script to output fewer sequences than expected. Here is one such infile with 9 hits, from which I was expecting only 4 sequences.**

**Note: this issue has been largely resolved based on the solution provided below the answer section**

```
Apil_comp16418_c0_seq1_OFAS000119-RA-EXON01 1587    Apil_comp16418_c0_seq1  2079    1   1   1587    1   416 2002    0.0 2931    100.00  1587    1587
Apil_comp16418_c0_seq1_OFAS000119-RA-EXON01 1587    Atri_comp13712_c0_seq1  1938    1   1   1587    1   1651    75  0.0 1221    80.73   1286    1593
Apil_comp16418_c0_seq1_OFAS000119-RA-EXON01 1587    Ctom_01003023.1 2162    1   1   1406    1   1403    1   0.0 1430    85.07   1197    1407
Atri_comp13712_c0_seq1_OFAS000119-RA-EXON01 1441    Apil_comp16418_c0_seq1  2079    1   1   1437    1   1866    430 0.0 1170    81.43   1175    1443
Atri_comp13712_c0_seq1_OFAS000119-RA-EXON01 1441    Atri_comp13712_c0_seq1  1938    1   1   1441    1   201 1641    0.0 2662    100.00  1441    1441
Atri_comp13712_c0_seq1_OFAS000119-RA-EXON01 1441    Acur_01000228.1 2415    1   1   1440    1   2231    797 0.0 1906    90.62   1305    1440
Ctom_01003023.1_OFAS000119-RA-EXON01    1289    Apil_comp16418_c0_seq1  2079    1   3   1284    1   1714    430 0.0 1351    85.69   1102    1286
Ctom_01003023.1_OFAS000119-RA-EXON01    1289    Acur_01000228.1 2415    1   1   1287    1   2084    797 0.0 1219    83.81   1082    1291
Ctom_01003023.1_OFAS000119-RA-EXON01    1289    Ctom_01003023.1 2162    1   1   1289    1   106 1394    0.0 2381    100.00  1289    1289
```

**Edit 2: There is still an occasional output lacking fewer sequences than expected, although not as many after incorporating modifications to my script from** Edit 1 **suggestion (i.e., accounting for reverse direction). I cannot figure out why the script would be outputting fewer sequences in these other cases. Below the infile in question. The output is lacking** `Btri_comp15171_c0_seq1`**:**

```
Apil_comp19456_c0_seq1_OFAS000248-RA-EXON07 2464    Apil_comp19456_c0_seq1  3549    1   1   2464    1   761 3224    0.0 4551    100.00  2464    2464
Apil_comp19456_c0_seq1_OFAS000248-RA-EXON07 2464    Btri_comp15171_c0_seq1  3766    1   1   2456    1   3046    591 0.0 1877    80.53   1985    2465
Btri_comp15171_c0_seq1_OFAS000248-RA-EXON07 2457    Apil_comp19456_c0_seq1  3549    1   1   2457    1   3214    758 0.0 1879    80.54   1986    2466
Btri_comp15171_c0_seq1_OFAS000248-RA-EXON07 2457    Atri_comp28646_c0_seq1  1403    1   1256    2454    1   1401    203 0.0  990    81.60   980 1201
Btri_comp15171_c0_seq1_OFAS000248-RA-EXON07 2457    Btri_comp15171_c0_seq1  3766    1   1   2457    1   593 3049    0.0 4538    100.00  2457    2457
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the expected output for the first problem. The second one seems to have it. You might also want to separate those two with more paragraphs and maybe headings.

Comment: which is your inifile

Comment: @simbabque, made it clearer

Comment: @ssr1012, infile is the blastn output

Comment: When you have duplicate blastn result then the subject length ,query length etc may differ. In that case which one you will consider?

Comment: @Arijit, from these particular blastn runs, they do not different in that regard, at least not for very many. This is due to a lot of previous filtering and comparisons during earlier analyses. If there are some that differ, then ideally the ones that have the longest `sstart` and `send` range.

Comment: Then you need to consier subject length(`send -sstart` ) while removing the duplicates.am I correct? Can you please help me to identify the code to print your sequence. then I can suggest you a way to print it.

Comment: This is the code that appears to print my sequences. Anything before really only generated the output files with no content `# iterate through the individual hits
for ($jter=0; $jter<$t1; $jter++) {
    (@templine) = split(/\s+/, $temparray[$jter]);
    $com = "./extract_from_genome2 $transcriptomes $templine[2] $templine[8] $templine[9] $templine[2]";
    # print "$com\n";
    system("$com");
    system("cat temp.3 >> $seqfname");
    } # end for ($jter=0; $jter<$t1...`

Comment: Do your sstart and send count the letters in the sequence beginning with 0 or 1? If you are off by 1, would it be correct to say `length = send - sstart +1`?

Comment: @Chris Charley - they start at one, but the currently proposed solution in the "Answer" section seems to have taken care of this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use hash to remove duplicates

The bellow code remove  duplicates depending on their subject length (keep larger subject length rows).

Just update your **# iterate through the individual hits** part with

```
# iterate through the individual hits
my %filterhash;
my $subject_length;
for ($jter=0; $jter<$t1; $jter++) {
    (@templine) = split(/\s+/, $temparray[$jter]);
        $subject_length = $templine[9] -$templine[8];
        if(exists $filterhash{$templine[2]} ){
                if($filterhash{$templine[2]} < $subject_length){

                        $filterhash{$templine[2]}= $subject_length;
                }
        }
        else{
                $filterhash{$templine[2]}= $subject_length;
        }
    }
my %printhash;
for ($jter=0; $jter<$t1; $jter++) {
    (@templine) = split(/\s+/, $temparray[$jter]);
        $subject_length = $templine[9] -$templine[8];
         if(not exists $printhash{$templine[2]})
        {
            $printhash{$templine[2]}=1;
            if(exists $filterhash{$templine[2]} and $filterhash{$templine[2]} == $subject_length ){

                    $com = "./extract_from_genome2 $transcriptomes $templine[2] $templine[8] $templine[9] $templine[2]";
                    # print "$com\n";
                    system("$com");
                    system("cat temp.3 >> $seqfname");
            }
        }
        else{
            if(exists $filterhash{$templine[2]} and $filterhash{$templine[2]} == $subject_length ){

                    $com = "./extract_from_genome2 $transcriptomes $templine[2] $templine[8] $templine[9] $templine[2]";
                    #print "$com\n";
                    system("$com");
                    system("cat temp.3 >> $seqfname");
            }
        }

    } # end for ($jter=0; $jter<$t1...
```

Hope this will help you.

**Edit part update**

for negative stand you need to replace

```
 $subject_length = $templine[9] -$templine[8];
```

with

```
if($templine[8] > $templine[9]){
                $subject_length = $templine[8] -$templine[9];
        }else{
                $subject_length = $templine[9] -$templine[8];
        }
```

You also need to update your `extract_from_genome2` code for negative strand sequences.

Comment: thanks for providing this. I tried running the script with the modification and got the following errors: `Bareword "subject_length" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at test.pl line 73.
Bareword "subject_length" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at test.pl line 81.` The relevant lines are `if(exists $filterhash{$templine[2]} and $filterhash{$templine[2]} < subject_length ){` and `if(exists $filterhash{$templine[2]} and $filterhash{$templine[2]} == subject_length ){`

Comment: I missed $ symbol in subject_length and I corrected it you can check now

Comment: Ok, I tried again, but now it doesn't produce an output file. I only updated the **# iterate through the individual hits** part of my script

Comment: This time I checked and updated the code. For me its working fine. you also check

Comment: Awesome! That definitely took care of the redundant sequence and base pair offset issues! Thanks @Arijit!

Comment: Well, it did what it was suppose to for some but not all. For example, I have an infile with 9 hits, and with this script, I should be getting 4 sequences. It only outputs 1 sequence. I'll modify my original post to provide the infile. I'm not sure if the script is having issues when a sequence's `sstart` and `send` are in the opposite orientation.

Comment: I also had the same thought before answering the question and to remove the duplicate you can consider the length column I believe which will be more appropriate. If you still want to calculate the subject_length using `sstart` and `send` you can put a `if condition` for reverse strand.forexample `if ($sstart >$send){$subject_length = $sstart -$send} `

Comment: Alright! Getting closer! I tried it with that infile and got the four sequences. Unlike the original solution, this time it doesn't seem to take care of the bp offset, i.e., I'm back to the sequences outputted being off anywhere from one to two base pairs, not that it is a really big deal in the end. I tried the suggestion by @Chris Charley and added `+ 1` to the end of `$subject_length = $sstart -$send` and `$subject_length = $send -$sstart`, but this didn't change anything.

Comment: Just did another spot check and found this that when using the script on this other infile (see edited post), `Btri_comp15171_c0_seq1` sequence was not outputted. In this case, i cannot figure out why it didn't.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118702/discussion-between-arijit-and-mike-f).

Comment: I just saw your comments. I've reached out to you via chat. Cheers!